# Default Web Site not displaying in localhost

Tags: google-chrome, http, iis, localhost, port

I was wondering if anyone can help with the following issue. We have IIS 10 enable on Windows Server 2016. If we open IIS and try to Browse the Default Web Site in http port 80, the localhost page in Chrome shows a blank page with the message:

```
{
  "succeeded": false,
  "message": "Authentication required",
  "code": 0
}
```

[image]The same happens if I enter the name of the server or 127.0.0.1, or if I use http or https

We still have not even published anything, only tried to see if the localhost page is showing.

The authentication is Anonymous Authentication Enabled. All the other options are disabled. The IIS logs are not storing anything, even though the option to store is enabled.
Windows firewalls are disabled.

I have compared the IIS default installation in another Windows Server 2016. Both have the exact same configuration, but this one for some reason does not work. I have also tried to restart IIS and reboot the machine.

Comment: What other software did you install on this server? Anything can take over localhost:80, as IIS/Windows HTTP API allows that.

Comment: I think there is a problem with authentication, can you show me the configuration in your iis?

Answer (score 0):

It is anonymous authentication:

- Anonymous authentication: Enabled
- ASP.NET Impersonation: Disabled
- Basic Authentication: Disabled
- Forms Authentication: Disabled
- Windows Authentication: Disabled

I have checked and port 80 is not used by any other application